# Passing in a Function with Parameters into a Child Component in React Native Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to pass the following function into a child component as a prop, along with a string parameter:

```
navigateToDetailsPage(nasaId: string) {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', { 
    nasaId: nasaId
  })
}
```

I pass in the function & parameter into the child component like so:

```
<NasaImage
  onPress={this.navigateToDetailsPage(result.data[0].nasa_id)}
  ...
/>
```

In the child component NasaImage I have declared onPress as:

```
onPress: () => void
```

However, I am getting the following error in the parent component:

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2322)
> NasaImage.tsx(12, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onPress'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in:

```
<NasaImage
  onPress={this.navigateToDetailsPage(result.data[0].nasa_id)}
  ...
/>
```

You passed the result of `this.navigateToDetailsPage(result.data[0].nasa_id)` function call (which returns void), while you want to pass an executable function instead.

To fix, use an arrow function:

```
<NasaImage
  onPress={() => this.navigateToDetailsPage(result.data[0].nasa_id)}
  ...
/>
```